# Getting data from list<MyCustomObject__c> with a List<String> of the Api Field Names

Tags: apex, visualforce, repeat

Been looking around for an alternative to manually writing the Api Field Name to display the data in an sObject List.

Normal Example:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!myCustomObjectList}" var="co">
     <apex:outputText value="co.customObjectFieldApiName1__c" />
     <apex:outputText value="co.customObjectFieldApiName2__c" />
     <apex:outputText value="co.customObjectFieldApiName3__c" />
</apex:repeat>
```

Instead of doing this for each row was playing around with using a `List<String>` of the field Api Names and iterating through that within the repeat.

Example (of what I'm trying to do):

In Controller:

```
List<String> customObjApiFieldNames = new List<String>

for (String s : schemaFieldSet) {
    SObjectField fieldToken = schemaFields.get(s);
    DescribeFieldResult selectedField = fieldToken.getDescribe();
    customObjApiFieldNames.add(selectedField.getName());
}
```

In VF Page:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!myCustomObjectList}" var="co">
     <apex:repeat value="{!customObjApiFieldNames}" var="coField">
         <apex:outputText value="co.coField" />
     </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

Of course this example doesn't work, so am looking for something along similar lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work you just need to change it little bit. For dynamic iteration of fields we pass them is sObject. This is similar with map iteration on visualforce.

```
  <apex:outputText value="co[coField]" />
```

The only thing you need to make sure here is you provide correct API name